# Express EJS: "Value Not Defined", But It's Inside an "If"

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In Node I am sending a `tasks` array to some routes, and not to others.  Here I am sending that `tasks` data:

```
pagedata = {
    title: 'Task List App',
    tasks: [{name: 'a task'}]   <---
}
 res.render('index', pagedata);
```

The markup in the EJS file has an `if` for that task data:

```html
<% if (tasks) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

That works fine.  But some pages won't have tasks, so that is why I am using `if`.  But when I don't include a `task` property on the `pageData` object like so:

```
pagedata = {
    title: 'Task List App'
}
 res.render('index', pagedata);
```

I get the error `tasks is not defined`.  I thought the whole reason you would use an `if` is because that data may not be there.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your variables are automatically passed through "locals" object by ejs, in your view simply do this :

```
<% if(locals.tasks) { %>
```

It prevent EJS to crash if some variable aren't defined.

In addition, this locals object is also present in res.locals (if you're using express) it implies that you can also define some variable/function for your view directly in middlewares :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
     res.locals.formatString = function(str){
         return str.toUpperCase();
     };

     res.locals.globalLang = "en";
     return next();
});

router.get("/index", function(req, res){
    res.render("index.ejs",{title: "index"});
});

// in index.ejs
<%- locals.formatString(locals.title); %>
<%- locals.globalLang; %>
....
```

Comment: That worked!  A little weird that the official docs at https://ejs.co/#docs would not have this.  And instead have the example I used which does not work...

Comment: Using the locals works like a charm.  Does EJS expose "globals" also?

Comment: I learned that [EJS app.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals) is also where what I was calling "globals" can be stored also.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask it like this:

```
<% if (tasks != undefined) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

Comment: `<% if (tasks != undefined) { %>` does not work.  Still `undefined`.